# Como esperar a que cargue jqery antes de renderizar DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Podrán ayudarme con los siguiente por favor...
Tengo una página en HTML que hace uso de jquery y otras librerias en JS, pero necesito esperar que primero se cargue todo el jquery antes de renderizar el DOM pues en ocasiones renderiza de manera correcta y en otras no debido a que no carga por completo la libreria

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  TODO EL DEMAS CODIGO----

  <script src="https://js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias en lo que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Se muestran errores en la consola cuando no la página no renderiza bien?

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de que estas importando Jquery desde el tag `<head>` y que no este al final de tu codigo HTML.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

Si tienes codigo que depende de Jquery y este esta siendo importado al final de este codigo, entonces dicho codigo se vera incapaz de acceder a Jquery.